# Receiving a 500 error when configuring an ASP.NET login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, forms-authentication

I want to add a login page to an ASP.NET Framework site, but the compiler doesn’t even load the view, instead throwing an error on the configuration.

The `web.config` contains the following configuration:

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

My `LoginController` contains the following:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But this is the error I receive:

> The configuration section 'authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: Post the entire contents of web.config

Comment: @abdusco: That would certainly be preferable, at least insofar as it would offer context around the `<authentication/>` element. Though, in this case, I think we can actually infer the problem based on the context revealed in the screenshot of the error page. See my answer below.

Comment: It's worth noting that while Forms-Based Authentication is easy to implement, it's really limited in what it can do, and it's no longer supported in ASP.NET Core. Modern ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core apps instead use ASP.NET Identity. It's more involved to setup and configure, but will make it easier to migrate to ASP.NET Core in the future, while also giving you a lot more options for authentication should you ever need them. (E.g., it can be used to authenticate using Google or Facebook authentication, or other OAuth compliant providers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<authentication/>` element was first introduced in ASP.NET 2.0 as part of [Forms-Based Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/forms-based-authentication), which appears to be what you’re trying to configure.

If so, it is expected under the `<system.web />` element ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/532aee0e(v=vs.100))):

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Login/Login"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You don’t provide the full context for your `web.config` file, but according to the screenshot of the error message, it appears as though you’ve inadvertently placed your `<authentication />` element as a *sibling* of the `<system.web />` element, not as a *child*.

The error message here certainly isn’t intuitive. But placing the `<authentication />` element under the `system.web` element should resolve your issue.

> ***Note:*** Since Internet Information Server (IIS) 7, there is *also* an `<authentication />` element located under the `<system.webServer />` element, under `<security/>` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/)). This is a used to configure IIS’s authentication, and is independent of the ASP.NET Framework’s Form-Based Authentication.